# Cannot find name 'Headers', 'RequestInit', 'Response'

Tags: module, header, response, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I updated my nativescript from the 2.5.2 to the 3.0.3. And suddenly when I try to run the app I get the following errors:

> node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(17,27): error
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'Headers'.
>
> node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(19,44): error
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'RequestInit'.
>
> node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts(19,66): error
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'Response'.

I don't understand why, because I think I'm not using this modules in my project.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Update your NativeScript-TypeScript plugin. - `npm i -D nativescript-dev-typescript@latest`

Answer (score 18):

add to tsconfig

```
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
]
```